# Nginx block all traffic except URL with specific format

Tags: nginx

I would like to allow access to an nginx server based web page from referrers that only contain the following "wp-admin" part of the url.

Every other access type/url should be denied. After hours of googling I can't seem to find the right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
location /secretpage {
    if ($http_referer !~ "wp-admin"){
            return 403;
    }
}
```